# checcking the details of individual certificate from avalilable certifcates

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I have one certificate installed in java and I can execute this command under the JRE security director:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

That gives me the list of installed certificates, but then I want to see the details of one individual certificate from that list. Say I get this result:

```
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 7D:6C:16:E4:FC:4D:D1:0B:10:BA:22:BB:4E:1C:6A:8E
verisignclass3g3ca, 25-Mar-2004, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): CD:68:B6:A7:C7:14:CE:71:E0:1D:4F:57:44:61:91:09
godaddyclass2ca, 11-Jan-2005, trustedCertEntry,
```

From this I want to see the details of the certificate named `verisignclass3g3ca` - when this certificate is going to expire and other details. How can I see that?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? There is a `-v` option that lists certificate details.

Comment: And there is an `-alias name` option that selects an entry to have its details listed when used with `-list -v` rather than pages for all of them. And if you don't have a local copy of the doc and can't reach any of the websites that have it, in Java>=7 `keytool -help -list` will display a handy summary of the options for `-list`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so what will be thhe final command plese advise